# Application Termination

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am running my app on a device. When I am in second view and terminate the app, the app quits but then when i launch it, it goes straight back to second view and not the first view (login view). I checked to see if the control goes to `applicationWillTerminate` method, but it does not go into that method. How can i make my program go into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably due to iOS 4's multitasking. When you tap the Home button, your application is by default suspended on supported devices (if you double tap Home, you can see all suspended applications). You can set the plist key  [UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23) to force UIKit to quit your application, rather than suspend, when the home button is pressed.

If you want to support the multitasking modes, look at the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method of your UIApplicationDelegate implementation.

Comment: As an addendum to your answer, unless you specifically opt out as you suggest, `applicationWillTerminate:` **NEVER** gets called...ever.