# App doesnt kill itself off when its closed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When i am using my app, and i press the back round button below the screen of the iphone, it exits the app. As you would expect.

If i then press the app icon the app loads up again, at whatever screen I was at in the app. Rather than starting again fresh at the Main Menu.

Is there some setting that allows this? Is there someway to disable whatever it is that causes the app to act in this way.

Phone is a 3gs and the OS version is 4.x.

Thanks
-Code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Termination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304598/application-termination)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of iOS 4, applications run in the background by default, unless you specify otherwise in your Info.plist file.

To kill the application when you press the Home button, place this in your Info.plist file:

`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` and set the value to `YES`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1

Comment: please, they don't run in the background :) They save the current state and resume.

Comment: @LordT: It depends on how the application is written. If the background operation queue is empty, then the app will save it's state and resume when it is relaunched. If the queue is not empty, it will perform the task(s) in that queue in the background.